# how can i run php in background in windows

Tags: php, windows, background

I have PHP code that gets data from one database to another database and works like a listener, i run it from the browser and it's working fine but I need to run it in the background in Windows OS

any help would be great.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. The easiest way is to remove any dependency from HTTP and make a command-line script; otherwise you'd need to use some command-line download tool. Then you have Task Scheduler. Not sure at what point you are or where you're stuck.